# Batched Downsizing of GB Sized TIF Images

Tags: command-line, batch-processing, image-resizing, tiff

I have 300+ TIFF images ranging in size from 600MB to 4GB; these are medical images converted from MRXS file format.

I want to downsize and make copies of the images at 512 x 445-pixel dimensions, as most of the files are currently sized at 5 figure dimensions (86K x 75K pixels). I need to downsize the files so that I can extract features from the images for a classification related problem.

I am using an i5-3470 CPU, Windows 10 Pro machine, with 20 GB RAM and a 4TB external HDD which holds the files.

I've tried a couple of GUI and command-based applications like XnConvert, Total Image Converter, but each GUI or CMD function causes the application to freeze up.

Is downsizing such large files even feasible using my hardware, or must I try a different command/BAT approach?

Comment: Try [libvips](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/HOWTO----Image-shrinking)

Comment: I have installed and placed the folder in my C: drive. I am trying to invert a picture, to test that it works, per the install guide, but I keep getting a "file not found" error. The image is all stored in the C: drive.                                                                                             
                                                                                                                  
C:\vips-dev-w64-all-8.8.3\vips-dev-8.8\bin>vips.exe invert Truck.png Truck.png
VipsForeignLoad: file "Truck.png" not found